# A problem with $\ell^{2}$-sequences which reminds me Fourier series but not exactly:)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Let $f\in\ell^{2}(\mathbb{Z})$, i.e, $f=(f_{n})_{n=\infty}^{\infty}$ and
$$
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}|f_{n}|^{2}<\infty.
$$
For $\theta\in(0,\pi)$ fixed, define
$$
g_{m}(\epsilon):=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-(\epsilon+i\theta)|m-n|}f_{n},
$$
where $\epsilon>0$ and $m\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Can the following assertion be true? The limit
$$
\lim_{\epsilon\to0+} g_{m}(\epsilon)=g_{m}
$$
exists for all $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ and the resulting sequence $g$ is bounded. (Or even $g\in\ell^{2}(\mathbb{Z})?$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it can't.

Consider $f_n = e^{i\theta n}/n$ for $n > 0$, $0$ otherwise.
Then

$$g_0(\epsilon) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-\epsilon n}/n \to \infty\ \text{as}\ \epsilon \to 0+$$